# Using PowerShell to set the Dynamics CRM 2011 Outlook Client Synchronization Process

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics-crm

We recently just moved from Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4 to Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 and are experiencing some performance issues with users on the Outlook Client. After reading this: http://blogs.neudesic.com/file.axd?file=2011%2F8%2FOptimizing+and+Maintaining+the+Performance+of+a+CRM+2011+Server+Infrastructure.pdf and from looking at the nature of the performance issues we are having, I believe that the issue is related to Outlook Client Synchronization.

In the above linked document it mentions that one can use the PowerShell to throttle Dynamics CRM Outlook Client Synchronization processes.

So I went ahead and ran the following two statements in Windows PowerShell:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Crm.PowerShell
Get-CrmSetting ThrottleSettings
```

and I get the following:

```
MapiSyncMaxConnectionsPerServer               : -1
MapiSyncPerOrgMaxConnectionsPerServer         : -1
MaxBackgroundSendEmailRequestsPerOrgPerServer : -1
MaxBackgroundSendEmailRequestsPerServer       : -1
OfflineSyncMaxConnectionsPerServer            : -1
OfflineSyncPerOrgMaxConnectionsPerServer      : -1
OutlookSyncMaxConnectionsPerServer            : -1
OutlookSyncPerOrgMaxConnectionsPerServer      : -1
ExtensionData                                 : System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject
```

However I don't exactly know what these values actually change and I cannot find anywhere else on the internet that will tell me. All the MSDN pages seem to show is that these values exist.

I can take a guess at what they mean, but I'd rather find out concretely before I go ahead and change things on a production server.

I'm thinking I need to use OutlookSyncMaxConnectionsPerServer and OutlookSyncPerOrgMaxConnectionsPerServer and that they limit the number of users that can sync at a given time.

However that is just a guess and in all honesty I have no idea what to set these values to.

I was hoping somebody here would know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find details of these settings here with the exception of what the default values are (typically a -1 value is just indicating that it's using the defaults that may have been set or embedded in the Microsoft CRM platform code and hasn't had a specific value set by an admin or user yet).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.deployment.throttlesettings_properties(v=crm.6).aspx

In answer to your root question about performance, it is likely more related to SQL Server performance.  You may be able to do some things like increase the default Microsoft Dynamics CRM Outlook setting for Minimum time between synchronization from 15 minutes to say 20 minutes and have a pretty positive impact on overall performance if you have hundreds or thousands of Microsoft CRM Users.  Otherwise, you may be better off looking more into the real reason for the performance issues in determining if they are related to networking (high latency or files not being cached) - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2012/04/09/using-the-crm-diagnostics-page-to-capture-network-performance.aspx .  If it's not network related, then you can focus on other areas like the Microsoft SQL Server performance.